Magento Open Source Extension for handling Master-Slave DB connections
Do you know of any extension for Magento Open Source that functions similarly to Adobe Commerce's Magento_ResourceConnections for managing master-slave database connections?
In Adobe Commerce, these configurations are typically defined in the env.php file, as shown:
<?php
return array (
    //...
    'db' =>
        array (
            'connection' =>
                array (
                    'default' =>
                        array (
                            'host' => 'default-master-host',
                            'dbname' => 'magento',
                            'username' => 'magento',
                            'password' => 'magento',
                            'active' => '1',
                        ),
                ),
            'slave_connection' =>
                array (
                    'default' =>
                        array (
                            'host' => 'default-slave-host',
                            'dbname' => 'magento',
                            'username' => 'read_only',
                            'password' => 'password',
                            'active' => '1',
                        ),
                ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
    ),
    //.......

The extension should handle database connections dynamically, routing read requests to the slave and write requests to the master.
If you know of any such extension, please let me know!
